# std::priority_queue removal order for duplicate priorities?

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

I know this is an implementation detail of std::priority_queue. I need to know because I'm reimplementing a priority queue in c# that needs to have the same removal behavior.

When I insert multiple items into a std::priority_queue that all have the same priority, what determines the removal order?

Comment: If the source of your implementation is available, study it. You should also write a test case that will check the behavior, e.g is it first in first out, first it last out, random, etc.

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap (what `std::priority_queue` uses): "The actual arrangement of the elements is implementation defined." EDIT: Actually it doesn't say explicitly that priority_queue uses it, just that it acts like it.

Comment: It is almost certainly undefined. The usual implementation with a heap can't preserve insertion order. You could do that yourself by including it as a subkey.

Comment: It has to be defined somewhere, even if only in the code. I'm just not sure where to look to find that out. Was hoping someone might know.